# Как достать имя типа из другого домена?

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Вот к примеру код:

```
var setup = new AppDomainSetup();
            setup.PrivateBinPath = $"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\\Libs";
var appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain( "имя домена", null, setup );
appDomain.DoCallBack ( AssemblyLoad );
```

Пример метода в калбэке:

```
private static void AssemblyLoad()
{
    var assembly = Assembly.Load( "Test" );
    var type = assembly.GetTypes().Single( t => typeof( НужныйТип).IsAssignableFrom( t ) );
    Console.WriteLine( type.FullName );
    _typeName = type.FullName;
}
```

переменная `_typeName` тоже статичная и остается при этом пустой. Если сделать метод не статичным, то каллбэк домена вызовет ошибку. Как узнать имя требуемого типа?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте дополнительный класс, наследующий от `MarshalByRefObject` и перенесите в него `AssemblyLoad`, `_typeName`, сделав их не статическими.

По непонятным причинам `DoCallBack` не работает (скорее всего, тянет за собой загрузку сборки в текущий домен), но работает `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap`:

```
class Test : MarshalByRefObject
{
    private Type _typeName;

    public void AssemblyLoad()
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.Load( "Test" );
        var type = assembly.GetTypes().Single( t => typeof( НужныйТип).IsAssignableFrom( t ) );
        Console.WriteLine( type.FullName );
        _typeName = type.FullName;
    }
}

// ...

var setup = new AppDomainSetup {
    PrivateBinPath = "Libs"
};

var appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("имя домена", null, setup);
var test = (Test)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, typeof(Test).FullName);
test.AssemblyLoad();
```

При этом возникнет следующая проблема: если вы попытаетесь обратиться к `test._typeName` в текущем домене, это повлечет загрузку в него сборки Test. Так как private path для текущего домена не прописан, возникнет исключение `FileNotFoundException`. Вам придется либо также настраивать private path для текущего домена, либо работать с загруженной сборкой исключительно внутри второго домена, передавая наружу только результаты ее работы.

Comment: Да, пока сборка лежит в той же папке, что и приложение, то все нормально. Но как только меняешь `PrivateBinPath`, то НЕстатичный метод выбрасывает ошибку.

Comment: @anweledig: Какую ошибку? (Если что-то про assembly loading, то что в fusion log?)

Comment: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` : `Дополнительные сведения: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "Test" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл.`

Из того, что поменялось - расположение файла и указание об этом в сетапе и собственно статичный метод переделан в нестатичный, со статичным все отлично работает.

Comment: @anweledig обновил

Comment: грустно это, спасибо за ответ)